# WC_Product::get_gallery_attachment_ids is deprecated since version 3.0

Tags: wordpress

When `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
and my php code

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 mb-xs-30"><?php // echo single_product_summary_sale_flash();?>
  <div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-allowfullscreen="native"> 

    <a href="#"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>

        <?php 
           global $product;

            $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

            foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
                $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>

                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $image_link;?>" alt="Xpent Super Shop "></a> 


                <?php  }
            ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> i can see a Notice, that is Notice:
>   WC_Product::get_gallery_attachment_ids is deprecated since version
>   3.0! Use WC_Product::get_gallery_image_ids instead. in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\wp\woocom\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3839  "

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 6):

problem solved ..
just replace

```
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
```

with

```
$attachment_ids =  $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
```

Answer (score -5):

open file /plugins/woocommerce/includes/legacy/abstract-wc-legacy-product.php

just comment wc_deprecated_function( 'WC_Product::get_gallery_attachment_ids', '3.0', 'WC_Product::get_gallery_image_ids' );

at line no 175.

And Enjoy

Comment: Never make changes on core files